# Get N number of columns from datatable c#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a datatable where I need to take n number of columns. For ex: From the below datatable I need to take first 10 columns alone with data and put it in another datatable.

**Code:**

```
DataTable dtRecord = DAL.GetRecords();
```

I tried this and this doesn't take the required column.

```
var selectColumns = dtRecord .Columns.Cast<System.Data.DataColumn>().Take(10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var selectColumns = dtRecord.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Take(10);

var dtResult = new DataTable();

foreach (var column in selectColumns)
    dtResult.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

foreach (DataRow row in dtRecord.Rows)
    dtResult.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray.Take(10).ToArray());
```

Perhaps you should create a column of the same type and with the same expression:

```
dtResult.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType, column.Expression);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this

```
private DataTable GetNColumnsFromDataTable(DataTable tblSource, int outputCols)
    {
        DataTable columnOutput = tblSource.Copy();
        if (outputCols > 0 && outputCols < tblSource.Columns.Count)
        {
            while (outputCols < columnOutput.Columns.Count)
            {
                columnOutput.Columns.RemoveAt(columnOutput.Columns.Count - 1);
            }
        }
        return columnOutput;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To copy from one `DataTable` to another, you can extract the columns of interest

```
var moveCols = dtRecord.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Take(10).Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

Then you must create new `DataColumn`s in a new table, then create new `DataRow`s in the new table:

```
var newTable = new DataTable();
foreach (var c in moveCols)
    newTable.Columns.Add(c);
foreach (var r in dtRecord.AsEnumerable())
    newTable.Rows.Add(moveCols.Select(c => r[c]).ToArray());
```

Which you can make an extension method on `DataTable`:

```
public static DataTable Slice(this DataTable dt, params string[] colnames) {
    var newTable = new DataTable();
    foreach (var c in colnames)
        newTable.Columns.Add(c, dt.Columns[c].DataType);

    foreach (var r in dt.AsEnumerable())
        newTable.Rows.Add(colnames.Select(c => r[c]).ToArray());

    return newTable;
}
```

Now you can call

```
var newTable = dtRecord.Slice(moveCols);
```

With a nice extension method, you can convert from `Dictionary`s to a `DataTable` dynamically:

```
var newTable = dtRecord.AsEnumerable().Select(r => moveCols.ToDictionary(c => c, c => r[c])).AsDataTable();
```

I have some for converting `ExpandoObject` and anonymous objects as well, as well as an extension to convert those to anonymous objects dynamically. Here is the code for `Dictionary`s to `DataTable`:

```
public static DataTable AsDataTable(this IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> rows) {
    var dt = new DataTable();
    if (rows.Count() > 0) {
        foreach (var kv in rows.First())
            dt.Columns.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value.GetType());

        foreach (var r in rows)
            dt.Rows.Add(r.Values.ToArray());
    }
    return dt;
}

public static DataTable AsDataTable(this IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> rows) => ((IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>)rows).AsDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get 10 columns:

```
 var tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
var cols = tbl.Columns.Cast<System.Data.DataColumn>().Take(10);
// if you wish to get first 10 columns...
```

If you want to get the data, then you have to loop through the columns to get the data.

```
var data = cols.SelectMany(x => tbl.Rows.Cast().Take(10).Select(y => y[x]));
```

of course, this will dump all the data into an ienumerable, if you want to use strong typed object or a list of one dimensional array, believe it's fairly simple, for example:

```
var data2 = cols.Select(x => tbl.Rows.Cast().Take(10).Select(y => y[x]).ToArray());
```

Comment: I am getting error in cast(). Casts the elements of an system.collection.IEnumerable to the specified type.

Comment: you can replace that by Cast<System.Data.DataColumn>()